# How to speed up this bottleneck: Loading a dictionary many times in Python

Tags: python, arrays, performance, numpy, dictionary

I wrote an algorithm that analyzes protein-RNA interactions and I found that the following function is the bottleneck that causes performance issues:

```
import numpy as np
#len(protein_sequence)~500, len(rna_sequence)~1500

def affinity_matrix(protein_sequence, rna_sequence): 
    python_matrix = [[] for _ in range(len(protein_sequence))]

    for i, AA in enumerate(protein_sequence):
        for base in rna_sequence:
            python_matrix[i].append(scales[base][AA])
            #(Where "scales" is a small dict() with the structure: 
            #scales[base][AA] = float(), with 4 bases and 20 AA, so 80 values total.)
    return(np.array(python_matrix))
```

I suspect 2 problems in this code, but I don't know how to solve them:

1. I am retrieving values from this "scales"-dict millions of times, and it's said
   calling values from "non-static" data structures like dict() is slow. So how can I make this
   small dictionary "static" instead? (This dictionary is only created once, while the rna_sequence and protein_sequence will be different each time I call the function.)
2. I am building the matrix at first with pythons tools, and later I
   convert it into the (faster) Numpy array. Possibly it is faster to
   directly create it with Numpy, but I am not sure if this is
   possible.

I am thankful for any tips how to improve this code or references to guides that would help in this case.

---

EDIT:

Here is example data, in case you want to try out the algorithm:

```
rna_sequence = 'ACAGGAGGAGCCGCUCGCUGGCGGCUGAUCCAGCGUCUCCGUGACAGGCACCCUGCUCCGCCGCCACCGCCACCGCCACCGCCACCGUCGCCUUUUCUUCUUCGUCCCGGGCGGUGCGUUCCACUGCUCUGGGGCCGGCGCCGCGCCCAGUCCCGCUUCGGGCCGCAAGCCCCACCGCUCCCCUCCCCGGGCAGGGGCGCCGCGCAGCCCGCUCCCGCCGCCACCUCCUCCCCUGCCGCCCUCCUAGCCGGCAGGAAUUGCGCGACCACAGCGCCGCUCGCGUCGCCCGCAUCAGCUCAGCCCGCUGCCGCUCGGCCCUCGGCACCGCUCCGGGUCCGGCCGCCGCGCGGCCAGGGCUCCCCCUGCCCAGCGCUCCCAGGCCCCGCCACGCGUCGCCGCGCCCAGCUCCAGUCUCCCCUCCCCGGGGUCUCGCCAGCCCCUUCCUGCAGCCGCCGCCUCCGAAGGAGCGGGUCCGCCGCGGGUAACCAUGCCUAGCAAAACCAAGUACAACCUUGUGGACGAUGGGCACGACCUGCGGAUCCCCUUGCACAACGAGGACGCCUUCCAGCACGGCAUCUGCUUUGAGGCCAAGUACGUAGGAAGCCUGGACGUGCCAAGGCCCAACAGCAGGGUGGAGAUCGUGGCUGCCAUGCGCCGGAUACGGUAUGAGUUUAAAGCCAAGAACAUCAAGAAGAAGAAAGUGAGCAUUAUGGUUUCAGUGGAUGGAGUGAAAGUGAUUCUGAAGAAGAAGAAAAAGCUUCUUUUAUUGCAGAAAAAGGAAUGGACGUGGGAUGAGAGCAAGAUGCUGGUGAUGCAGGACCCCAUCUACAGGAUCUUCUAUGUCUCUCAUGAUUCCCAAGACUUGAAGAUCUUCAGCUAUAUCGCUCGAGAUGGUGCCAGCAAUAUCUUCAGGUGUAACGUCUUUAAAUCCAAGAAGAAGAGCCAAGCUAUGAGAAUCGUUCGGACGGUGGGGCAGGCCUUUGAGGUCUGCCACAAGCUGAGCCUGCAGCACACGCAGCAGAAUGCAGAUGGCCAGGAAGAUGGAGAGAGCGAGAGGAACAGCAACAGCUCAGGAGACCCAGGCCGCCAGCUCACUGGAGCCGAGAGGGCCUCCACGGCCACUGCAGAGGAGACUGACAUCGAUGCGGUGGAGGUCCCACUUCCAGGGAAUGAUGUCCUGGAAUUCAGCCGAGGUGUGACUGAUCUAGAUGCUGUAGGGAAGGAAGGAGGCUCUCACACAGGCUCCAAGGUUUCGCACCCCCAGGAGCCCAUGCUGACAGCCUCACCCAGGAUGCUGCUCCCUUCUUCUUCCUCGAAGCCUCCAGGCCUGGGCACAGAGACACCGCUGUCCACUCACCACCAGAUGCAGCUCCUCCAGCAGCUCCUCCAGCAGCAGCAGCAGCAGACACAAGUGGCUGUGGCCCAGGUACACUUGCUGAAGGACCAGUUGGCUGCUGAGGCUGCGGCGCGGCUGGAGGCCCAGGCUCGCGUGCAUCAGCUUUUGCUGCAGAACAAGGACAUGCUCCAGCACAUCUCCCUGCUGGUCAAGCAGGUGCAAGAGCUGGAACUGAAGCUGUCAGGACAGAACGCCAUGGGCUCCCAGGACAGCUUGCUGGAGAUCACCUUCCGCUCCGGAGCCCUGCCCGUGCUCUGUGACCCCACGACCCCUAAGCCAGAGGACCUGCAUUCGCCGCCGCUGGGCGCGGGCUUGGCUGACUUUGCCCACCCUGCGGGCAGCCCCUUAGGUAGGCGCGACUGCUUGGUGAAGCUGGAGUGCUUUCGCUUUCUUCCGCCCGAGGACACCCCGCCCCCAGCGCAGGGCGAGGCGCUCCUGGGCGGUCUGGAGCUCAUCAAGUUCCGAGAGUCAGGCAUCGCCUCGGAGUACGAGUCCAACACGGACGAGAGCGAGGAGCGCGACUCGUGGUCCCAGGAGGAGCUGCCGCGCCUGCUGAAUGUCCUGCAGAGGCAGGAACUGGGCGACGGCCUGGAUGAUGAGAUCGCCGUGUAGGUGCCGAGGGCGAGGAGAUGGAGGCGGCGGCGUGGCUGGAGGGGCCGUGUCUGGCUGCUGCCCGGGUAGGGGAUGCCCAGUGAAUGUGCACUGCCGAGGAGAAUGCCAGCCAGGGCCCGGGAGAGUGUGAGGUUUCAGGAAAGUAUUGAGAUUCUGCUUUGGAGGGUAAAGUGGGGAAGAAAUCGGAUUCCCAGAGGUGAAUCAGCUCCUCUCCUACUUGUGACUAGAGGGUGGUGGAGGUAAGGCCUUCCAGAGCCCAUGGCUUCAGGAGAGGGUCUCUCUCCAGGACUGCCAGGCUGCUGGAGGACCUGCCCCUACCUGCUGCAUCGUCAGGCUCCCACGCUUUGUCCGUGAUGCCCCCCUACCCCCUCACUCUCCCCGUCUCCAUGGUCCCGACCAGGAAGGGAAGCCAUCGGUACCUUCUCAGGUACUUUGUUUCUGGAUAUCACGAUGCUGCGAGUUGCCUAACCCUCCCCCUACCUUUAUGAGAGGAAUUCCUUCUCCAGGCCCUUGCUGAGAUUGUAGAGAUUGAGUGCUCUGGACCGCAAAAGCCAGGCUAGUCCUUGUAGGGUGAGCAUGGAAUUGGAAUGUGUCACAGUGGAUAAGCUUUUAGAGGAACUGAAUCCAAACAUUUUCUCCAGCCGGACAUUGAAUGUUGCUACAAAGGGAGCCUUGAAGCUUUAACAUGGUUCAGGCCCUUGGUGUGAGAGCCCAGGGGGAGGACAGCUUGUCUGCUGCUCCAAAUCACUUAGAUCUGAUUCCUGUUUUGAAAGUCCUGCCCUGCCUUCCUCCUGCCUGUAGCCCAGCCCAUCUAAAUGGAAGCUGGGAAUUGCCCCUCACCUCCCCUGUGUCCUGUCCAGCUGAAGCUUUUGCAGCACUUUACCUCUCUGAAAGCCCCAGAGGACCAGAGCCCCCAGCCUUACCUCUCAACCUGUCCCCUCCACUGGGCAGUGGUGGUCAGUUUUUACUGCAAAAAAAAAAAAAGAAAAAAGAGAAAGAAAAAAAAGAAUGAAUGCAAGCUGAUAGCUGAGACUGUGAGACUGUUUUUGUCCACUCUUCUGAAUCACUGCCACUUGGGUCAGGGACCACAGCCAUUGCCACCCUUGGCCCAUCUCUCUGCGUGCGUGCCUUGAGCACACAUAUAAAAAGUGCCAUGUGCAAUUGUCUUAUCUUUUAUGAUCUAGGCUUUGCCUAGGGAUCACUACUCCUUAACGGGCUGGCUGGGGCAAUGAGGAAAAGCUCCUUUGCUCCUGUAAGGCCAUAAGUGGCUGUUAACAGAUUUUCAAAUGCCUGAAGAGAUUGCUGAGACCUGCUAGAGUCAUAUGUUCGGGGAAUUAAGUCUUUAUCCUAGACAACAAGGUACAGAUGCAAACUGCAGUGUUAUUGGAGGGUCAAUCGGCAAGGAUAUGAUUAUCCCAAAAUGGAGUUCAUCGACCCUAGCUUUCCUUUAGAUUAUAUAUAAAUAAAAGUGCAGUCCUCUUCUAAUGGCCACAGUUGGUUUUCUUGUAGCCCAGAAAGUCCAAAUUAAAGGAAAUAAAUUCAGUUUUAUGUUAGCCUUCCUUGGUGCAUCAGGGUGUCAGUGGAAAUAGGAUCAGGUGGUGUGUGUGUGUGUGUUUUGUGUGUGUGUGUACACAUGUGUUUAUAUAUACAUGUGUGAGGGAAAGUGUGUACAUAUAUGUAGGAUUGUAACCAGACGGAAAAGAACGAGGAUCUCCAGGGUGUUUGAAUCAGCAACAGAUUUGUGUUUUCUAACAUGCAUUUAGUUGGAGAGGCAUGGUUCUGUUUGUUUUGUUUUGAUCUAAUUUGCCAUUGGAAAUAGGUACAGUUACACAGAGAAGGAAGAACCAGGAAAGUGAGAUCCAUGAAACUAAAUGAGCAGCUGUCAGAAUCCAGUGUGGCUGAGCCUACCUAGCUUAUGAAAUCUAACCCAGGGUUCCCUGAGUCCAAGACCACUUAGAUUAUUAAGAUUUUGAACGUCCAGAGGAGUGAAAAGUCUGUUUUCUGACGUAAGCCGGAGCUGAGGAUAAAGCCAGAGGCCAGUGGAUUAGGUGUAUGGAAUGUGGAUGGAGAGGGCUUGUGUGGGAUGUGGCCAGGGAGUGGGUGAGGAAGGCCGCUUCUAAAUGGCCUGUAAAAACUUGAGAUUGGAUAGACGAAAGGAAAUGGAGAAAUUAAAGAAUUGGAGAAACUAGUUAUCUGUGUUGCUGACUUUGGGACCCAUCCAAGACUCCUGCCCUUGGGGUGUUCCAUGGUGGUUUCUUCCUGCCUGGGCGCCACCCUUUCCCCAGUUCAGGCCCUCCCUGGAGGACUAGUUUGUGUAUUGGUAUCCUCCCCAGUGGACCCAAACCAGCGCAUACUUGGUGUGUGGAGAUGGGAGACAAAGGACAGAUCUAGGAGCCUUGAAGGAUCACCAGCCACCGACCCUCCAUCAGGGCCAACUGGGCAGGAAAGGGAACAUUGCAGACCUGAUUUCCCGACGAUGUCACCCUGUCCUCCCUCCUUGCUUCUUGCUCUGCUAACUCAACUCUGCCUUCCUCUUUUUCAUUCUUCUACUCUGCCCUAUAUGGAGGACAAAUGGACACCAGGGGUGCUAACCUUAUUGGUGCCUGCCCCAGCCUACCCCAGGUGCCAGCAGACUCUCGUGCACAGGAGGCUCCCACAGUUAUGGAGCCAGGAAAGAAUUUCUCUGCACUGGAUGGACUGUAUAUUGAGAUUAAAAAUUAUAUUCCUUAUAUUCCUGCUUAUAUCAAUGCUCUCUCUGUAAAACCUCUUCCUAGCCUCAUUUCUCUCAACUGAUCUUGUUUAGGCGUUGUAUUCCUUUUAUUUACUCUUUGCUUGACUGCUUCCUCCUAACCCUCUACCCACUAGCACUCUACUUCCUAAAGCUGUUGUGUCAUUAACUCUGUUGGAUCAACUCUCUGGGAAAAGAUUCUGUUAAUGUAAGUGCACUUACUCCCUGGAUGUUGUCACUAGUCUAGUGGCUUUUGCUAAAUAAACCUUUCUUAUUUCUA'
protein_sequence = 'MPSKTKYNLVDDGHDLRIPLHNEDAFQHGICFEAKYVGSLDVPRPNSRVEIVAAMRRIRYEFKAKNIKKKKVSIMVSVDGVKVILKKKKKLLLLQKKEWTWDESKMLVMQDPIYRIFYVSHDSQDLKIFSYIARDGASNIFRCNVFKSKKKSQAMRIVRTVGQAFEVCHKLSLQHTQQNADGQEDGESERNSNSSGDPGRQLTGAERASTATAEETDIDAVEVPLPGNDVLEFSRGVTDLDAVGKEGGSHTGSKVSHPQEPMLTASPRMLLPSSSSKPPGLGTETPLSTHHQMQLLQQLLQQQQQQTQVAVAQVHLLKDQLAAEAAARLEAQARVHQLLLQNKDMLQHISLLVKQVQELELKLSGQNAMGSQDSLLEITFRSGALPVLCDPTTPKPEDLHSPPLGAGLADFAHPAGSPLGRRDCLVKLECFRFLPPEDTPPPAQGEALLGGLELIKFRESGIASEYESNTDESEERDSWSQEELPRLLNVLQRQELGDGLDDEIAV'
scales = {base:{AA: 1.1111 for AA in "DTSEPGACVMILYFHKRWQN"} for base in "AGCU"}
```

Comment: Might be better suited for Code Review which handles things such as efficiency and performance.

Comment: Thanks, I will do so in future! But now there is a good answer here and it would be a loss to delete it.

Answer (score 2):

IIUC, you could use a [nested list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3.7/tutorial/datastructures.html#nested-list-comprehensions) which avoids using append:

```
def affinity_matrix(protein_sequence, rna_sequence): 
    return np.array([[scales[base][AA] for base in rna_sequence] for AA in protein_sequence])
```

Comment: Thanks for this great point! I wouldn't have imagined that append() was the problem! So you think the dictionary is fine?

Answer (score 1):

> I am loading this dictionary millions of times, and it's said loading "non-static" data structures is slow. So how can I make this small dictionary "static" instead?

How about using one flat dictionary using tuples (base, AA) for keys, instead of nested dictionaries? You can retrieve the value like `scales[(base, AA)]`. I suggest to try this, but not completely sure if this improves the performance, as get operation on dict is said to be O(1) in average.

> I am building the matrix at first with pythons tools, and later I convert it into the (faster) Numpy array. Possibly it is faster to directly create it with Numpy, but I am not sure if this is possible.

It is possible to do that, and should perform much faster. Would be looking like this.

```
shape = len(protein_sequence), len(rna_sequence)
arr = np.empty(shape)
for i, AA in enumerate(protein_sequence):
    for j, base in enumerate(rna_sequence):
        arr[i, j] = scales[base][AA]
```

### Updated

As I did some examination, list comprehension as in Daniel's answer was somewhat faster than my answer above using for loop.

And it was much much faster using generator.

```
np.array(((scales[base][AA] for base in rna_sequence) for AA in protein_sequence))
```

Comment: Very interesting that this is even faster. Thanks for all the input! I will check how your dictionary-circumvention influences the performance. It's a great idea to use tuples!